# Opening Termux to the entire phone

Tags: termux

I think I have a memory leak on my phone. So I installed Termux then htop via `pkg`. When I opened htop, I could only see two processes--what seemed to be the instance of Termux, and htop.

How can I use Termux to access the rest of the phone, but *without* rooting (I want to still do banking on my phone)?

Comment: Base don your description I assume your phone has Android 10 or 11. On that versions apps can't see other apps processes. And termux apps are installed into private app data that can only be accessed with root permissions. Therefore you have to install htop manually e.g. to `/data/local/tmp`.

Comment: use adb shell, run custom (static) binary from /data/local/tmp